# Javascript Syntax error (Newbie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code that I have been working on for some time. I had orginally tried to achive what i wanted using an array but this was overwhelming for me. I have scince attempted to modify my code to achive a conditional statment.

```
var settings = {
    objSlideTrigger: '#one,#two,#three,#four,#five,#six'
} // link button id

if (objSlideTrigger: '#one') { // This is the line im getting a syntax error on.
    objSlidePanel: '#content-one'
}
else if (objSlideTrigger: '#two') {
    objSlidePanel: '#content-two'
}
else if (objSlideTrigger: '#three') {
    objSlidePanel: '#content-three'
}
else if (objSlideTrigger: '#four') { 
    objSlidePanel: '#content-four'
}
else if (objSlideTrigger: '#five') {    
    objSlidePanel: '#content-five'
}
else if (objSlideTrigger: '#six') { 
    objSlidePanel: '#content-six'
};
};
```

That particular chunk of code is assigned the seetings for a function that slides a web element 'div' across the page using href links. the problem i had was that the href link would move all the six seperate divs at once.

My solution, though it may not be the best is to create six links that each handle their own divs. However the settings require the id's of both the links and the divs. I need the user to be able to decide what dive they want to see by clicking on the coresponding link.

As im fairly new to javascript the only ways that i knew i could possibly achieve such a thing was by either making two arrays one for the links and one for the divs. and when the user selected the link they want it would pull the href element from the array and insert it into the settings. Or alternativly have a bunch of conditional statments although  a slightly more messy approach.

If anyone can help me solve this issue or find a better alternative to it, i would be very greatful. Thanks again in advance and i have included a js fiddle that shows the basics of the javasript code and what it does on page.

http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/6/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic syntax error.

Comment: The whole logic of that short snippet is way off. That's just not how objects work; you can't just invent a syntax and hope that it works.

Comment: No, I need to be able to change the settings of the fiddle 'I.e. the html element ID depending on the element Id the user has chosen.

Comment: @elclanrs, it appears you did not read the whole question, yes i have a syntax error, however im searching for a correct or alternate way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set a value to objSlideTrigger in every if statement you must use == instead.

Try this considering objSlideTrigger is "#one" or "#two" etc.. and not all of them at the same time

```
if (settings.objSlideTrigger == '#one') 
//  ^^^^^^^^                 ^^ not :
```

Change on all else if aswell to ==

Comment: `objSlideTrigger` is not a variable, it's a property of `settings`, and also, it's value will never match `#one`, you would need a regex of some description.

Comment: A Regex, sounds exactly what I need, I need to assign a new settings property everytime a user clicks a different link. I'll do some research on this Regex and attempt a fix. Thank you.

Comment: or, since you're starting, maybe go for an `indexOf('#one') != -1`? it's a tad simpler than throwing yourself at regular expressions off the bat. tho yeah, `/#one/g` would do the trick, `new Regexp( varname , 'g' )` if you want it dynamic.